# How do I keep a table and caption together on the same page in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have not found an answer to this.  I have a table in Microsoft Word 2016.  When I add a caption to the table, the caption appears in a random text box that often float off the page.

I have almost decided that the only way to keep this from happening is to add a row to the table that doubles as column headers and a caption.  Otherwise, I have to constantly fight this randomly positioned caption.  Is there any official way to (1) prevent the caption from appearing in these randomly positioned text boxes and (2) keep captions and tables together - right now my caption is on one page and my table on another page.

Answer (score 2):

Select the Caption paragraph and the table. Then from the **Format Paragraph** dialog choose the **Line and Page Breaks** tab. On that tab is a checkbox for **Keep with next**. Mark it.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I don't see where either of those words was used in this thread. Maybe your comment was destined for a different post?

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Keep with next does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep with next does not work, but there is another option underneath it called "Keep lines together" which is what they meant I think

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).